# SQL Server Management Studio VS Visual Studio - Different version of SQL

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I would love to manage and create my databases in SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio and use them in Visual Studio but I can't connect to the same database :

[Different Version of SQL used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRnlk.png)

As you can see, Visual Studio is connected to SQL Server 13.0 and Management Studio is connected to SQL Server 12.0.

Can someone help me to figure this out and make the two programs using the same database.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Judging by the screenshot, one is connecting to an instance of LocalDB, and the other to an instance of SQLExpress. Have you got them both running on the same machine? I haven't got any experience of this, but know LocalDB is a flavour of SQL Express. I don't know if you can run them simultaneously, or if SSMS is just reporting LocalDB as SQL Express in the GUI, but it's worth checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are connected to different instances of SQL Server. Visual Studio is connected to a `LocalDB` instance while SQL Server Management Studio is connected to SQL Server Express instance. To resolve this issue you just select local instance at login step of SQL Server Management Studio tool.

Comment: Yes thanks, was just indeed changing the Server Name at the login screen to connect !

Thanks for your replay